# checking the string against all values of multidimension hashmap in perl

Tags: perl, hashmap, hashtable

I have the below requirements

- Read the sample data file /tmp/user_defined_connection.ini

---

```
MANAGEMENT=IDL||CIDL
NORTH=IDL,NORTHERN||VIDL,NORTH||IDL,NORTH
SOUTH=IDL,SOUTHERN||CIDL,SOUTH||IDL,SOUTH
```

- Each Key here can have the multiple such values ',' signifies an AND operations and '||' is an OR operation
- I need to check this against another string $instance and for each value , so I take the first key MANAGEMENT and get its values and check against isntance ....

`$instance` contains `IDL` or `CIDL`

In next iteration same instance will be checked against the second key which is `NORTH` and if true the function should return NORTH so basically I need to check the instance against each value one by one and then return the key which i find the last... below is the code written till now

```
#!/sbin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @providerCloudSequence;
my %idlcodes;
open(my $iniFH, '<', '/tmp/user_defined_connection.ini') 
    or die "Unable to open file:$!\n";

while(<$iniFH>) {
    chomp;
    my @providerCloudClass = split('=',$_);
    push @providerCloudSequence, $providerCloudClass[0];
    if ($@) {
        print "Script Failed to get the Sequence....Exiting the Script\n";
        exit 1;
    }

    #my %idlcodes = map { split /=|\s+/; } <$iniFH>;
    my ($k, @r) = split /=|\Q||/;
    $idlcodes{$k} = [ map [ split /,/ ], @r ];
}
if($@){
        print "Script Failed to create the hash....Exiting the Script\n";
        exit 1;
 }
close $iniFH;
print Dumper \%idlcodes;
        my @interfaceSampleAliases = { "AFGHD_NORTH", 
                                           "NORTHERN_IIDID_IPV123", 
                                           "IDL_SOUTH", 
                                           "IDL_SOUTH_IUID", 
                                           "SOUTHERN_IND_IPV" };
        foreach (@interfaceSampleAliases){
            my $correctKey = getCorrectKey($_, %idlcodes, @providerCloudSequence)
            print $correctKey;
        }

}
# Providercloudsequence helps to maintain the precedence of the input file
# idlcodes is the hasp map where key is the key from file and value is an arracy of arrays ...see below the output of same

sub getCorrectKey($$$){
        my $interfaceAlias = $_[0];
        foreach ($_[2]) {
    # This is where I need the help , I want to get the value from 
    # hash %idlcodes using the key from @providerCloudSequence
    # The value of %idlcodes is kind of multiple Arrays where I want to 
    # grep $interfaceAlias against each with a AND in between elements 
    # and OR in between arrays , if true this is match
        }
}
```

##Data Dumper Output : Hash looks like

```
'NORTH_IPV' => [
                           [
                             'IDL',
                             'NORTHERN'
                           ],
                           [
                             'VIDL',
                             'NORTH'
                           ],
                           [
                             'IDL',
                             'NORTH'
                           ]
                         ],
          'MANAGEMENT' => [
                            [
                              'IDL'
                            ],
                            [
                              'CIDL'
                            ]
                          ],
          'SOUTH_IPV' => [
                           [
                             'IDL',
                             'SOUTHERN'
                           ],
                           [
                             'CIDL',
                             'SOUTH'
                           ],
                           [
                             'IDL',
                             'SOUTH'
                           ]
                         ]
```

Expected output

```
InterfaceAlias         correctKey

 "AFGHD_NORTH"           Doesnt Match anything so return NULL
 "NORTHERN_IIDID_IPV123" Doesnt Match anything so return NULL
 "IDL_SOUTH",            SOUTH_IPV
 "IDL_SOUTH_IUID",       SOUTH_IPV
 "SOUTHERN_IND_IPV"      Doesnt Match anything so return NULL
 "IDL_NORTH_IPV"         NORTH_IPV
 "IDL_ABDGJF"            MANAGEMENT
```

How the check should work in this example

checks if InterfaceAlias contains (IDL OR CIDL) , then checks if same interfaceAlias contains [(IDL AND NORTH) OR (VIDL AND NORTH) OR (IDL AND NORTHERN) , then checks if same interfaceAlias contains [(IDL AND SOUTH) OR (CIDL AND SOUTH) OR (IDL AND SOUTHERN)]

So we have to check against all values in hash %idlcodes and return the last key with which match was TRUE

The sequence is managed by the array `@providerCloudSequence`

Adjacency of words is not important For example SOUTH_XXX_CIDL or even "SOUTH IDL IPV WITH SPACES" should match SOUTH_IPV....These are just examples it is basically a contains match....though the structure of file is fixed...(the data may vary)

Comment: You need better and more exact details of the inputs and expected return value from your "getCorrectKey" sub.  It's pretty difficult to understand what you really want to do! Hope this helps

Comment: @Vorsprung I have added the sample inputs and outputs

Comment: @mpapec ....New Post as suggested

Comment: Is your example correct? According to your ini file, `SOUTH` corresponds to `IDL,SOUTHERN` or `CIDL,SOUTH` and not `IDL,SOUTH`. Also, would something like `SOUTH_XXX_CIDL` match anything, or is the order and adjacency of the words important?

Comment: @Borodin No example is correct , see the last value SOUTH_IPV does have a value IDL,SOUTH....Adjacency of words is not important yes SOUTH_XXX_CIDL or even "SOUTH IDL IPV WITH SPACES"  should match SOUTH_IPV....These are just examples it is basically a contains match....though the structure of file is fixed...(the data may vary)

Comment: Ah I see. The ini file you show doesn't correspond to the dumped hash, that's all.

Comment: @Borodin Changed the file....any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would build a table of regular expressions from the ini file and then simply compare the strings one by one.

My suggested code is below. The `get_correct_key` now converts all underscores to hyphens and trips out all the junk so, for example, `SOUTH-GWS-F-IDL100555236-Primary-1Gb` is converted to `SOUTH-GWS-F-IDL-Primary-Gb`. That has allowed me to simplify the regex substantially too.

Some notes on your code

- It is superior to `use warnings` instead of adding `-w` to the shebang line
- Capital letters in identifiers are generally reserved for globals like packages, and anyone familiar with Perl would thank you to stick to lower case and underscores for simple variables and subroutines
- `$@` is only set when a piece of Perl code fails to compile or calls `die`. It is only caught by `eval`, and if you aren't using that then your tests on `$@` will always fail
- You should *never* use prototypes on a Perl subroutine definition. They are different from prototypes in other languages and don't do what you think

I hope this helps

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $ini, '<', 'user_defined_connection.ini' or die $!;

my @provider_patterns;

while (<$ini>) {
  next unless /\S/;
  chomp;

  my ($key, $data) = split /=/, $_, 2;
  my $regex = join " |\n", map {
    join ' ', map { "(?=.* \\b $_ \\b )" } split /,/;
  } split /\|\|/, $data;

  push @provider_patterns, [ qr/$regex/xi, $key ];
}

my @aliases = (
  'AFGHD_NORTH',
  'NORTHERN_IIDID_IPV123',
  'IDL_SOUTH',
  'IDL_SOUTH_IUID',
  'SOUTHERN_IND_IPV',
  'IDL_NORTH_IPV',
  'IDL_ABDGJF',
  'IDL SOUTH',
  'MANAGEMENT_IPV_IDL100595208',
  'SOUTH-GWS-F-IDL100555236-Primary-1Gb',
);

for my $alias (@aliases) {
  my $found = get_correct_key($alias, \@provider_patterns);
  printf qq{ %-38s %-s\n}, qq{"$alias"}, defined $found ? $found : "Doesn't match anything so return undef";
}

sub get_correct_key {
  my ($alias, $patterns) = @_;
  $alias =~ tr/_/-/;
  $alias = join '-', $alias =~ /[a-z]+/gi;
  my $found;
  for my $pair (@$patterns) {
    my ($re, $key) = @$pair;
    $found = $key if $alias =~ $re;
  }
  $found;
}
```

**output**

```
 "AFGHD_NORTH"                          Doesn't match anything so return undef
 "NORTHERN_IIDID_IPV123"                Doesn't match anything so return undef
 "IDL_SOUTH"                            SOUTH_IPV
 "IDL_SOUTH_IUID"                       SOUTH_IPV
 "SOUTHERN_IND_IPV"                     Doesn't match anything so return undef
 "IDL_NORTH_IPV"                        NORTH_IPV
 "IDL_ABDGJF"                           MANAGEMENT
 "IDL SOUTH"                            SOUTH_IPV
 "MANAGEMENT_IPV_IDL100595208"          MANAGEMENT
 "SOUTH-GWS-F-IDL100555236-Primary-1Gb" SOUTH_IPV
```

Comment: I added some more inputs like 
  "IDL SOUTH".....It treats this as two diff words and output comes as `"IDL"                   MANAGEMENT
 "SOUTH"                 Doesn't match anything so return undef
`  MANAGEMENT_IPV_IDL100595208....This fails as well...Can we please say a word starts with alphabet and ends with alphabet

Comment: The first one fails because I have used `qw` to populate the array `@aliases`. Are all your words going to be alphabetical, i.e. no numbers? That would make it simpler. In fact, are they all capital letters?

Comment: I'm not near a keyboard right now so I can't fix it at present.

Comment: There are can be numbers followed by words as in example above....another good example would be `SOUTH-GWS-F-IDL100555236-Primary-1Gb`  This is should go to SOUTH_IPV........@Borodin No problem whenever u get a minute..

Comment: I mean all the words in the *criteria*. Are you ever going to need to check for, say, `1Gb`, or `IDL123A`?

Comment: No wont check but what I am showing to you is actually the data from production which can change and i dont have absolute control on that so i want to make this as generic as possible with whatever conditions I understand......Will Check only IDL not IDL123A

Comment: @ Borodin ...On a very diff note I thought grep function might have been useful in this case (My earlier code)....but not so sure how to use this...

Comment: OK will that do? I can really help any more til tomorrow.

Comment: @Borodin...Yes that will do ,,,thanks for today will wait for tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah try it as it is now. See if you can make it break and post here. I'll pick up in the morning.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41569/discussion-between-borodin-and-learner)

Comment: first of all thanks for the snippet can you please if possible explain me what exactly is happening here, like the creation and comparison part.